# Eclipse PDT does not recognize FuelPHP Autoloader's Core Namespaces

Tags: php, eclipse, namespaces, fuelphp, eclipse-pdt

FuelPHP provides a functionality in its Autoloader class called "core namespaces" (added via `Autoloader::add_core_namespace($namespace)` ) which essentially maps the specified namespace into the global namespace, so that core namespaces can be used as if their classes were defined in the global namespace. For example, I can define

```
namespace This\Is\A;
class Test {}
```

and then call

```
Autoloader::add_core_namespace('This\Is\A');
```

in order to use `\Test` to refer to the class normally found at `\This\Is\A\Test`.

This is a nice feature, but Eclipse PDT does not know how to handle this and cannot resolve `\Test`, putting warnings everywhere that the class is not recognized, instead.

I was wondering if there was a way to manually define these mappings in a project-specific way that Eclipse PDT would recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a file like this? https://gist.github.com/kenjis/2364280

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but it works! Thanks!